# Which snowy township mobile game with character chat bubbles is this?

Tags: game-identification, mobile

I was watching [this mobile phone review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCjeBHhUSfo&t=38s) on YouTube recently, at 38 seconds the presenter is playing a mobile game that caught my attention. I'm eager to embark on this gaming adventure, but there's one hitch – I have no idea what the game is called!

I've attached an image I captured from the video:

[image: Mobile game - snowy township in a forest, with a campfire, and NPCs chatting]

It looks like the characters are saying:

> **Character 1**: I never thought we'd be able to settle here...
> **Character 2**: ...and provide shelter to others
> **Character 3**: I'm so relieved

If any of you can identify this game, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Additionally, if you could provide a link to download it from the App Store or Google Play and let me know whether it's a free or paid game, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that's ***Frozen City***.  Similar screenshots can be seen on [this site](https://gamingonphone.com/guides/frozen-city-beginners-guide-and-tips/).

Google Play Store link can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fct.global).

Comment: thanks for finding me the game.